calling a method on tkinter
I'm having an issue trying to use the destroy() method in python.
I have created a class and was trying to make a window that would bring me to different frames, and destroy the ones I was on before.
from tkinter import *
import sys, os                       
class Interface:
    def startGame(self):
        frame.destroy()

        frame2 = Frame(window,background = "black")
        frame2.place(x=100,y=220)

        entry = Entry(frame2, bg="black",fg = "white",font=("Comic Sans", 30,"underline"))
        entry.pack()
        
        login = Button(frame2,text="Login")
        login.pack()

        cancel = Button(frame2,text="Cancel",command = window.mainloop)
        cancel.pack()
        
    def loadGame():
        pass

    def firstWindow(self):
        frame = Frame(window)
        picture = PhotoImage(file="dinossaur.png")

        label = Label(frame,
                      text="Final Project: Ultimate",
                      font=("Comic Sans", 40, "italic"),
                      fg="gray",
                      background = "maroon",
                      #relief = RAISED, bd = 10, padx = 9, pady = 9
                      image=picture,
                      compound = "bottom")
        frame.pack()
            
        start = Button(frame, text="Start Game", command =self.startGame)
        load = Button(frame,text="Load Game", command = self.loadGame)
        exitB = Button(frame,text="Exit",command = window.destroy)

        label.pack()
        start.place(x=220,y=240)
        load.place(x=220,y=270)
        exitB.place(x=220,y=300)

    # to change icon on top left!
    ##icon = image(file="logo.png")
    ##window.iconphoto(True, icon)


window = Tk()
window.geometry("640x480")
window.title("Final Project: Ultimate")
window.config(background="maroon")

game = Interface()
game.firstWindow()

window.mainloop()

But whenever I run it, I find a couple of issues:
the image is not showing, and startGame() gives me the following error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\betoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1962, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:/Users/betoi/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/finalProject/interface.py", line 5, in startGame
    frame.destroy()
    ^^^^^
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Frame'?


frame is a local variable which only exists as long as the function is executed in which it was created. Even if the same variable name appears in multiple functions, the variables are not related.

As said in above comment, use instance variable self.frame instead of local variable frame.  Same for local variable picture to fix the image issue.


@Michael Butscher and acw1668' comment.

The problem can be fixed.
Use self.frame and self.picture instead of local variable frame and picture.
Screenshot:


You are trying to reach a variable that is out of scope. If you want to access class object attributes (variables) you can use self. By using self one can access the variables that are specific for the object created by the class. The whole point of object oriented programming is that multiple objects can be created that hold different values.
See it like if you and a classmate have the same bag. However, his bags holds a Introduction to English book, while your bag holds a Introduction to Algorithm book. Same, same, but different.

class Interface:

    def startGame(self):
        self.first_window_frame.destroy()
        ...



    def firstWindow(self):
        self.first_window_frame = Frame(window)
        ...

Reference
Extra tip: Explicit is better than implicit.
Try to make your variable names more readable/explicit. You are now referencing you frames by numbers. When the codebase increases by size it will get harder to figure out which frame is what. Call it what it is.
Zen of Python
